# How to steal cookie on website with cors?

Tags: cors

When I make a cross origin request to example.com from anysite.com with

`req.withCredentials = "true";`

cookies are included in the request

The response contains

```
access-control-allow-origin: https://anysite.com
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-expose-headers: WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization
```

In this particular case, cookies values can be used to calculate the Authorization header value that can be obtained by manipulating cookie values.

I just want to extract cookies.

Any idea how to do that?

The target site doesn't have a CRLF vulnerability.

Comment: I take it that "example.com" requires this authentication sent in a separate header, rather than just using session cookies? Normally CORS configured like that allows you to basically "remote control" the victim's session n the vulnerable site, and it doesn't matter what the cookies actually are, only that the victim's browser have them be set.

Comment: @Doe: I've noticed that you changed my edit (CRLF into CSRF) back. While it is widely known what a [CSRF vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) is I think you need to explain what this CRLF vulnerability should be if you insist that you mean CRLF and not CSRF.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CRLF_Injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attacker might influence what gets sent within a cross-origin request but he is not able to read the cookies which gets added by the browser to the cross-origin request. Even a wide open CORS policy does not change this.

An attacker might also not change where the cookies get send: cookies will only be sent to the site where they belong to, no matter what CORS policy exists.